# ECONNRESET when connecting to ArangoDB cluster

Tags: kubernetes, arangodb

I've set up an arangodb cluster within google cloud kubernetes. When I try to call methods using ArangoJS, it randomly throws following error.

> Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
>       at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:580:26)
>     code: 'ECONNRESET',
>     errno: 'ECONNRESET',
>     syscall: 'read',

Also within the error there's a line with

> authorizationError: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN',

It doesn't seems to occur when the server is already reading from the database, but when it reads from database after some idle period. (There's a load balancer in-between also)

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Try running it locally on minikube and see if it reproduces. I suspect this is a config issue with your ArangoDB. See arangodb docs or ask them to provide documentation on how to run it on Kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks. Will check...

Comment: Same problem... My client is a Google Cloud Functions trying to connect to my cluster (Google Cloud Compute) through the public IP. Randomly -rarely- getting `Error: read ECONNRESET` when calling `POST /_db/topicseed/_api/cursor`)

Comment: did you find any solution???.